# Sample AnimatedGrid from Flutter docs doesn't find the widget?

Tags: flutter

From [AnimatedGrid](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedGrid-class.html) running:

```bash
flutter create --sample=widgets.AnimatedGrid.1 mysample
```

The sample code does not find the `AnimatedGrid`. What is missing?

Running `flutter analyze` or `flutter run` shows following messages:

[image]

Comment: restart the IDE and try again?

Comment: I am not using IDE. Simply running on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`AnimatedGridState` is provided by [`firestore_ui`](https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_ui) package, add it on `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firestore_ui: ^1.24.0
```

And import it on that file. It isn't adding on `pubspec.yaml` while generating the project.

Comment: Why a third-party package? `AnimatedGridState` is part of standard flutter widgets. It is on `animated_scroll_view.dart` of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets

Comment: I cannot find on v3.3.10, can you include your flutter version

Comment: Yes you are right. I cannot find it on v3.3.10. It was originally in `animated_grid.dart` and then moved into `animated_scroll_view.dart`. But is there any mention to the required version  in the official flutter docs to use the AnimatedGrid?

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

Related Issue: [Stable documentation contains widgets that do not appear in the stable channel](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118161)